# Dropping '#NULL!' from df

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import some simple likert-scale data and plot it using a stacked horizontal bar graph.

```
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\..."
datafile_name = "Motivators.xlsx"
datafile = path + datafile_name

xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(datafile)
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')
df = df.drop('Email_Address', 1)

print df[:10]
df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

I don't know how exactly `pd.ExcelFile()` works, but is there an option for **DROPPING `#NULL!` VALUES?**

I have ~3000 records with `#NULL!` entries

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `#NULL!` with `NaN`s and then `dropna`.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, "#NULL!"])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
        0
0       1
1       2
2       3
3  #NULL!

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [3]: df.replace('#NULL!', np.nan)
Out[3]: 
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3 NaN

[4 rows x 1 columns]

In [4]: df.replace('#NULL!', np.nan).dropna()
Out[4]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Even better would be to specify that `#NULL!` is a NaN while importing with `na_values='#NULL!'` in `pd.read_excel()`.